# What are eclipse debug prespective analogs for VS F10 and F11?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

So I am kind of new to eclipse so I wonder what are  "debug prespective" short cut analogs that work like Visual Studio `F10` and `F11`?

Comment: Eclipse users aren't going to know what F10 and F11 do on Visual Studio. Explain what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`f10` in VS is `f6` in eclipse (step over)

`f11` in VS is `f5` in eclipse (step into)